# Cast iron drain pipe replacement

Tags: drain, cast-iron

I live in a ranch with a concrete slab for a foundation built in 1956. The kitchen drain feeds into the pipe under the concrete where it is rotted or collapsed. This 2 inch pipe runs approx 18 feet to the main drain out in the center of the house.

Since I know I will need to cut the concrete and dig the old out to replace it, I need to know what kind of connectors should I use to connect an 10ft and 8ft piece together. I just don't think the rubber seal with clamps are the correct type for underground use. Any Ideas on what is?

Thanks for any assistance provided

Comment: Side Note about your repair: Around here (Dallas Tx) they do a lot of tunneling under the foundation from the outside to replace old plumbing. It may be a cheaper alternative to cutting up your concrete slab. Since you will not have to repair the floor / sub floor. Additionally, less mess in the house. Good luck with the repair.

Answer (score 1):

You should use plastic (ABS) for any replacement runs if possible. Yes you can use clamp couplings underground (for iron-to-iron and iron-to-plastic connections) but not just any type. You need heavy duty clamps listed for that service (not cheap "no-hubs" from the ubiquitous orange big box). 
We call them "mission bands" but that is a brand name (no endorsement) that has become a common moniker.
Of course, you should check with your local code enforcement authority.

[image]

Comment: What you're showing here *is* a no no-hub connector. It's the generic term for a clamp that forgoes the need for cast iron hub fittings. They sell the fully enclosed ones at the big-box stores too, so no need to be bashing them. It's up to the consumer to select the right part. I agree that the full metal band should be used underground, and really anywhere.

Comment: Any reason you're suggesting ABS in particular? If you prefer it over PVC you should state why. I used to PVC with good results in my last bust-up-the-floor job.

Comment: In Dallas TX much cast iron drain replacement is done by tunneling from outside  under the slab. Perhaps we can do this here because many locations the soil is clay and so the sides of these tunnels do not collapse.

Comment: thank you Friend. Looking at what was being recommended didn't seem like a more permanent solution, but if there is a solid connector, i will find it.  I will contact my retailor ( non bigbox) and see what they have.